# Display attribute on standard style sheet effecting my handheld style sheet?

Tags: css

I am trying have some images hidden when viewed on a desktop but visible when viewed on a mobile device.  I have 2 separate styles linked like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="handheld.css" media="only screen and (max-device-width:480px)"/>
```

but when i use the display: none; or visibility: hidden; on the style.css it also hides it on my mobile, why is this?  Other styling to the handheld.css work fine and only on my phone.

Comment: How can anyone answer this when you do not provide the relevant CSS?

Comment: @thatidiotguy: There were formatting problems with the question; now fixed.

Comment: I was just doing that myself, thank you

Comment: Try this tutorial? http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't put a media query on `style.css`, so it gets used for all devices.

You need to either exclude it from handheld devices, or have `handheld.css` override those rules.